# NSSpeechRecognizer delegate never called

Tags: macos, cocoa, speech-recognition, speech

I'm trying to get speech recognition working on a MacBook (OS 10.8.2) but I *never* get any callbacks on the delegate method.  Using XCode 4.6 with ARC, here is my simple test code.  I do get the "listening" output in the console.  The "microphone" appears on screen and if I press the ESC key, then I can see my speech pattern in the display of the microphone, but still no delegate callbacks ever.   There must be something basic missing but I haven't found it.

I've looked at numerous SO questions but none solve this.  Some talk about calibration in the control panel, but I find nothing there for calibration (maybe that was a previous OS?).

Full project source available in [github](https://github.com/progrmr/RB2/tree/origin/RB2).

```
#import "RBListener.h"

@interface RBListener() <NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSSpeechRecognizer* recognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong)           NSArray*            commands;

@end

@implementation RBListener

@synthesize recognizer = _recognizer;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // initialize
        _commands = @[@"hi", @"yes", @"no", @"hello", @"good", @"time"];

        _recognizer = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
        _recognizer.delegate = self;
        _recognizer.commands = _commands;
        _recognizer.listensInForegroundOnly = NO;
        _recognizer.blocksOtherRecognizers  = YES;
        [_recognizer startListening];
        DLog(@"listening");
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate methods
- (void)speechRecognizer:(NSSpeechRecognizer*)sender didRecognizeCommand:(id)command
{
    DLog(@"command: %@", command);
}

@end
```

[image: screen shot while dictating]

Comment: I'm not sure if it has much to do with your question as a whole, but Calibrate is still present. In "System Preferences" select "Accessibility", select "Speakable Items" on the left, and the "Settings" tab.

Comment: @NJones aha, that explains why I couldn't find the calibration, I was looking under "Dictation & Speech" in Preferences.  I will try calibrating but I'm not sure it will help.

Comment: Calibration *was* the problem.  Since I've calibrated it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your RBListener instance isn't sticking around (or is never even created), so right after everything's set up, there's no RBListener instance to receive the delegate messages.

The easiest thing to do is create an outlet in your XIB and connect it to an RBListener instance. That is, drag a basic "NSObject" (plain cube) into your xib from the library and change its class to "RBListener". This instance can then be referenced via your outlet (once you connect it in IB) AND should stick around in memory.

If you're alloc/initing your RBListener instance programmatically, make sure you're storing it somewhere (like as an instance variable on some other object that sticks around - your app delegate or your NSDocument subclass - whichever is appropriate to your design). If you don't stash it into a property or make it a singleton (another possible approach), ARC will kill it before you get a chance to use it since you did nothing to hold onto it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I do get the "listening" on the console, so I know it's created.  The obj ref is stored into a strong property but I'll double check this when I get back home.

Comment: Okay, so you're creating the object but it's not sticking around or you haven't set it as the speech system's delegate. Add a property to something that does (like your app delegate) and assign it to that property upon creation if you don't have it sticking around or make sure you're setting that instance as the delegate after it's created.

Comment: I did set the delegate, as you can see above, right after the alloc.  Also, it is not being deallocated, I just confirmed that, it is in a property with a strong reference.

Comment: You have not said anything about where you're creating this object. Whether you're creating it in some method somewhere (what? where?) or it's waking from a xib, for example.

Comment: It's a property in RBMain, which is a held by a property of the App Delegate.  It's a very small test app so I pushed it to [github here](https://github.com/progrmr/RB2/tree/origin/RB2/RB2) if you want to look at the other classes.

Comment: It turns out the problem was that it required calibration in Settings.  Once I did that it started working.